# OSSEC active response host deny configuration

Tags: linux

I'm trying to configure OSSEC Active-response for having the host-deny command to block IP's within a timeframe of 600 s alert level or above.

```
  <active-response>
    <command>host-deny</command>
    <location>local, server</location>
    <level>10</level>
    <timeout>3600</timeout>

  </active-response>
```

Can I add the timeframe to the following code with at least 3 alerts within 600s or above within x number of seconds, but unblock after a period of y seconds if no more activity.

Also, is it possible to whitelist some IP's in the a local configuration on the server, not in the global configuration?